# SAS- rank variables conditional on value of variable

Tags: sas, finance

I am writing a SAS code, and I have the following issue. I have a table of financial data, and I want to rank the data (stocks) into groups according to a variable, but I want to omit the stocks for which the price (another variable) is less than 5. However, I don't want to just delete all stocks whose values are less than 5 at some date, as then I would need to calculate the returns of the ranked stocks- Hence if a stock is now at 10 but it is 3 in 2 months, I want to have it in the data today, but "not have it in the data" in 2 months.

For the moment my code is:

```
proc sort data=umd; 
    by date; 
run;

proc rank data=umd out=umd1 group=10;
    by date;
    var cum_return;
    ranks momr;
run;
```

Could you please help me with that?

Comment: Am I misreading this, or is there a reason you couldn't just add `where price ge 5;' to the proc rank statement?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the " where= " option at dataset out=umdi. This will not delete the records only subset the output dataset.

```
    proc rank data=umd out=umd1(where=(price > 5)) group=10;
        by date;
        var cum_return;
        ranks momr;
    run;
```